# Class to simplify background thread creation and UI thread synchronization

Tags: android

What class does Android use to simplify background thread creation and UI thread synchronization?

Comment: [Udacity course page from which this question is copy-pasted](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1469948762/e-1530568562/m-1484928604)

Comment: To be fair, the Udacity course instructions specifically suggest using StackExchange to find the answer to the question.

Comment: That question is part of an online Udacity Android training class. People asking that question are looking for that exact answer and nothing more.

Comment: @alcfeoh I have got to disagree. Some people are looking for the exact answer, the majority are looking for insights on the AsyncTask class

Comment: ..which if this question wasn't already on here verbatim I was about to do it- since Udacity does specifically encourage students to use SO.. which I agree with wholeheartedly

Answer (score 61):

AsyncTask is the class you are looking for.

You can find more information about it within the [official Android Documentations.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: For this to be a valuable answer, you will need to expand on why AsyncTask is useful in solving OP's problem.

Comment: Well, since we now know the class name can't someone simply go to the Android docs and get that info? Make sure you flame Kshitij as well for not providing an essay on why AsyncTask is useful. You want to be fair right?

Answer (score 20):

[`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

Answer (score 8):

1. `AsyncTask` is the class when you have some simple tasks to run in background. But it is not good is there are too many tasks.
2. `Service` is the component that android provided for the developer to use to do background task. And you could use binder or Messenger to communicate with `Activity` or UI thread.
3. And you Surly could create new thread from your `Activity` or `Application`. It depends on your demand or situation.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to the Udacity course question, the class would be AsyncTask 
[i.e. this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Why the need for this answer, when the question already has already had a much better answer since May 2015?

Comment: Identical to alcfeoh's answer.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify background thread creation and ui thread sync android uses AsyncTask class

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) is deprecated. [Kotlin concurrency utility classes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) are the recommended way to handle Threads.